# Delta table not avaialbe from SQL enpoint, but it works well from notebook

Tags: azure-storage, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have mounted Azure Data Lake Storage in databricks with:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
source = "abfss://{0}@{1}.dfs.core.windows.net/".format(container_name, storage_account_name),
mount_point = mount_path,
extra_configs = cfg
    )
```

After this I created a new delta table:

```
create table {database}.{my_tablename} (t1 int, t2 int) location 'dbfs:/mnt/{my_path}'
insert into {my_database}.{my_tablename} values (99, 99)
```

The table works fine in the notebooks.
I can query the data. Also, I see that a proper folder with the delta table is created in the container.

The problem is when I try to query the data from SQL Endpoint -
I get these errors:

```
dbfs:/mnt/{my_path} doesn't exist
```

OR

```
{my_database}.{my_tablename} is not a Delta table.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be working correctly today.
I waited around 12 hours.